# How to pull all the unique combinations from a list of lists

Tags: python, list, loops

I want to iterate over a list of lists, and pull all the combinations from the lists.

I can do it in the following way:

```
list = [['1','2','3'],['a','b','c'],['x','y','z']]
for itemi in list[0]:
    print itemi
    for itemj in list[1]:
        print itemi+itemj
        for itemk in list[2]:
            print itemi+itemj+itemk
```

My problem is that I want to do it over a varying number of lists in the list o' lists. There will be at first just one list, and (for now) end with 64 lists.

The above example is for 3 lists, and in reality all the lists contain the same values (zero to 255). I used the above examples just so you can see what the output should look like.

I figured there must be a better way to this, without having to build the nested for loops for each size of list of lists.

Comment: Could you please describe in more detail what you mean by 'pull all the combinations from the lists'?

Comment: please add the output you want

Comment: sure - I want to make a set of variables that represents every combination of each of the elements in the list of lists. In the above example, the outputs would be 1, 1a, 1ax, 1ay, 1az, 1b, 1bx ... 3b, 3bx, 3by, 3bz, 3c, 3cx, 3cy, 3cz.

Comment: @JayGattuso Please edit your *question* with the additional details.

Comment: How are `1` and `3b` *combinations* of three lists?

Comment: @Tichodroma  I agree, I guess there is a forth item in each list, of a null value. Apologies for not being clear.

Comment: don't use the name `list` as a variable name as you thereby shadow the built-in function `list()`.

Comment: @moooeeeep aye, I just caught that, thank you. I forgot it was a reserved name. Thanks for letting me know - its the kind of thing that can stump me for a while! :)

Comment: have a look at [PyChecker](http://pychecker.sourceforge.net/). It should give you a warning where you shadow a built-in.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.product):

```
>>> l = [['1','2','3'],['a','b','c'],['x','y','z']]
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.product(*l))
[('1', 'a', 'x'), ('1', 'a', 'y'), ('1', 'a', 'z'), ('1', 'b', 'x'), 
 ('1', 'b', 'y'), ('1', 'b', 'z'), ('1', 'c', 'x'), ('1', 'c', 'y'), 
 ('1', 'c', 'z'), ('2', 'a', 'x'), ('2', 'a', 'y'), ('2', 'a', 'z'), 
 ('2', 'b', 'x'), ('2', 'b', 'y'), ('2', 'b', 'z'), ('2', 'c', 'x'), 
 ('2', 'c', 'y'), ('2', 'c', 'z'), ('3', 'a', 'x'), ('3', 'a', 'y'), 
 ('3', 'a', 'z'), ('3', 'b', 'x'), ('3', 'b', 'y'), ('3', 'b', 'z'), 
 ('3', 'c', 'x'), ('3', 'c', 'y'), ('3', 'c', 'z')]
```

This is not quite what you want yet, but it's easy to get there:

```
>>> for i in range(len(l)):
...     print(list(itertools.product(*l[:i+1])))
...
[('1',), ('2',), ('3',)]
[('1', 'a'), ('1', 'b'), ('1', 'c'), ('2', 'a'), ('2', 'b'), ('2', 'c'), 
 ('3', 'a'), ('3', 'b'), ('3', 'c')]
[('1', 'a', 'x'), ('1', 'a', 'y'), ('1', 'a', 'z'), ('1', 'b', 'x'), 
 ('1', 'b', 'y'), ('1', 'b', 'z'), ('1', 'c', 'x'), ('1', 'c', 'y'), 
 ('1', 'c', 'z'), ('2', 'a', 'x'), ('2', 'a', 'y'), ('2', 'a', 'z'), 
 ('2', 'b', 'x'), ('2', 'b', 'y'), ('2', 'b', 'z'), ('2', 'c', 'x'), 
 ('2', 'c', 'y'), ('2', 'c', 'z'), ('3', 'a', 'x'), ('3', 'a', 'y'), 
 ('3', 'a', 'z'), ('3', 'b', 'x'), ('3', 'b', 'y'), ('3', 'b', 'z'), 
 ('3', 'c', 'x'), ('3', 'c', 'y'), ('3', 'c', 'z')]
```

Get everything in one list:

```
>>> result = []
>>> for i in range(len(l)):
...     result.extend(list(itertools.product(*l[:i+1])))
...
>>> result
[('1',), ('2',), ('3',), ('1', 'a'), ('1', 'b'), ('1', 'c'), ('2', 'a'), 
 ('2', 'b'), ('2', 'c'), ('3', 'a'), ('3', 'b'), ('3', 'c'), ('1', 'a', 'x'), 
 ('1', 'a', 'y'), ('1', 'a', 'z'), ('1', 'b', 'x'), ('1', 'b', 'y'), 
 ('1', 'b', 'z'), ('1', 'c', 'x'), ('1', 'c', 'y'), ('1', 'c', 'z'), 
 ('2', 'a', 'x'), ('2', 'a', 'y'), ('2', 'a', 'z'), ('2', 'b', 'x'), 
 ('2', 'b', 'y'), ('2', 'b', 'z'), ('2', 'c', 'x'), ('2', 'c', 'y'), 
 ('2', 'c', 'z'), ('3', 'a', 'x'), ('3', 'a', 'y'), ('3', 'a', 'z'), 
 ('3', 'b', 'x'), ('3', 'b', 'y'), ('3', 'b', 'z'), ('3', 'c', 'x'), 
 ('3', 'c', 'y'), ('3', 'c', 'z')]
```

Get it in the exact shape you want:

```
>>> sorted(result)
[('1',), ('1', 'a'), ('1', 'a', 'x'), ('1', 'a', 'y'), ('1', 'a', 'z'), 
 ('1', 'b'), ('1', 'b', 'x'), ('1', 'b', 'y'), ('1', 'b', 'z'), ('1', 'c'), 
 ('1', 'c', 'x'), ('1', 'c', 'y'), ('1', 'c', 'z'), ('2',), ('2', 'a'), 
 ('2', 'a', 'x'), ('2', 'a', 'y'), ('2', 'a', 'z'), ('2', 'b'), ('2', 'b', 'x'), 
 ('2', 'b', 'y'), ('2', 'b', 'z'), ('2', 'c'), ('2', 'c', 'x'), ('2', 'c', 'y'), 
 ('2', 'c', 'z'), ('3',), ('3', 'a'), ('3', 'a', 'x'), ('3', 'a', 'y'), 
 ('3', 'a', 'z'), ('3', 'b'), ('3', 'b', 'x'), ('3', 'b', 'y'), ('3', 'b', 'z'), 
 ('3', 'c'), ('3', 'c', 'x'), ('3', 'c', 'y'), ('3', 'c', 'z')]
```

Comment: `itertools` to the rescue! (as always)

Comment: can you constrain it use less than the full list of lists? (e.g. only use l[0] to 1[1]. I could iteratively clip the full list until  and operate on the reduced version until I reach the limit, but I wondered if there is a way to do this within the itertools lib? EDIT: ha, beat me to it! thank you. Another nice tool to learn! :) I appreciate your time.